# How can I sum two fields and store the result in a third field on a MySQL table autonomously?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update, mysql-error-1442

I created a simple `UPDATE AFTER INSERT` trigger to sum two `DECIMAL(10,2)` fields and update a 3rd `DECIMAL(10,2)` field with the summed value.

The trigger code is:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER calc_ttl_cost AFTER INSERT ON buybox_rec
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
      UPDATE buybox_rec SET total_cost = (price+shipping_cost);
  END;
|
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin to run the SQL commands, so I know that the trigger is being created successfully.  Furthermore, if I run the `UPDATE buybox_rec SET total_cost = (price+shipping_cost);` SQL statement alone, it works as expected. (I've also tried the same code with back-ticks around the field names, but I wouldn't be writing all this if that worked)

The problem is that when I insert a new row, the trigger doesn't work and this error is thrown:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'buybox_rec' in stored function/trigger 
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored 
unction/trigger.
```

The error seems like some sort of recursive or circular reference problem, but I can't figure out where/what the problem is.

I also tried creating a stored procedure and calling it from within the trigger to try obtaining the same result, but I got the same error.

I checked a bunch of other SO questions related to MySQL UPDATE triggers and did some Googling, but here I am.

Is this out of the scope of MySQL? It seems like such a common and easy task to allow for.

Does anyone know how I accomplish this task autonomously? (AKA I don't want to hear about summing the fields after the fact via PHP, for example)

THanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to modify the contents of a table which is already being used by the UPDATE + TRIGGER operation. This simply can't be done, but you have alternatives.

For example, if your meaningful data (or independent variables) are price and shipping cost while the total cost depends on them, you could keep only the first two in your table, and maybe have a very simple VIEW (something like `SELECT price, shipping_cost, price+shipping_cost total_cost FROM buybox_rec`, or whichever other fields you need) if you want to keep an eye at the total.